How to change outgoing exim port in cpanel
Suppose my ISP blocked outgoing port 25, so the issue is I cannot send email from cPanel account by using port 25 (I have root access to my WHM/cPanel account).
How can I change the exim outgoing port 25 to another port like 587? I mean when I send email, it should try to connect to port 587 on the recipient server.
How can I do this? I read this doc but it only changes the listening exim port: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360052485333-How-do-I-change-my-Exim-SMTP-port-from-25


How can I change the exim outgoing port 25 to another port like 587? I mean when I send email, it should try to connect to port 587 on the recipient server.

That's useless, as the recipient's server 1) is not guaranteed to listen on port 587, or have that listener available to the public Internet, and 2) most likely will not accept external mail via port 587.
For example, Gmail's MX servers do not listen on :587 at all – they are completely separate from the "mail submission" servers (which likewise do not listen on port 25). My workplace uses a single server for both MX and mail submission, but it strictly requires user authentication for the latter before it'll accept any mail.
(After all, that's the whole reason for two different ports – ISPs block 25 and allow 587 precisely because the latter is usually configured to not accept external mail.)
You can change the port number used by editing the configuration for the smtp transport, specifically the port = option (add if missing) – there are plenty of examples for configuring a relay host that uses port 587, so you can take just the port-related half of such an example – but it'll only work with very few recipients.
Instead, you really should talk to the support staff of whatever is providing you with the WHM/cPanel account.

Wow! What a complete answer that I didn't know some of them. Thanks a lot my friend. Also I upvoted your answer but my reputation is less than 25, so it doesn't show. That was a great thing I learned.
